# suggestions to optimize a nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have the following code written with the help of users here.

But i still have high cpu usage problem

I would appreciate notes and suggestions to refine this code.

The goal of this code is to query two tables from 5 different database and return the results in an array

then the client will filter the result and show the appropriate result.

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cluster = require('cluster');
var static=[];
var clients = [];
var dbs=[];
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : '',
    user     : '',
    password : '@@'
});

if(cluster.isMaster){
    cluster.fork();
    cluster.fork();
    cluster.fork();
}else{

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        clients.push(socket);
        socket.on('disconnect',function() {
            clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
        });
    });

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        connection.query('use nodejs');
        connection.query("SELECT db_name,domain_name FROM tbl_dblist",function(err, rows, fields){
            rows.forEach(function(v1){
                dbs.push({'db':v1.db_name,'site':v1.domain_name});
            })
        })
        connection.release();
    });

    setInterval(
        function(){
            pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){

                dbs.forEach(function(v1){
                    connection.query('use '+v1.db);
                    connection.query("select value as jackpot,sum(playnum) as played,sum(amount) as total,count(user_id) as player from tbl_config,tbl_user where header='jackpot_amount' ",function(err,rows){
                        static[v1.site]={'played':rows[0].played,'total':rows[0].total,'player':rows[0].player,'jackpot':rows[0].jackpot}
                    });
               })


                connection.release();

            });

            clients.forEach(function(cl,ind){
                qq=cl.handshake.query.domain;
                cl.emit('static',static[qq]);
            });


        },2500);


    console.log('Listen On Port 3001');
    app.listen(3001);

}
```

I have a big issue too

in browser console log o get this a lot

```
GET http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3001/socket.io/?domain=XXX&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1420913085882-3 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Comment: What "high cpu usage problem"?

Comment: I have about 40% cpu usage , about 2.1k user online